# Turing completeness of feed-forward neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, computation-theory

I read that RNN are Turing complete but feed-forward neural networks (FFN) are not.  But based on universal approximation theorem, FFN can simulate any functions given enough nodes, and we also know that lambda Church calculus (which is based on stateless functions) is equivalent to Turing machine, why can't FFN be Turing complete by simulating arbitrary functions in Church calculus?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is probably not suitable here.  I would recommend Cross Validated, Computer Science or Computational Science SE.

Comment: Can you provide citation for "FFN are not Turing-complete"?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I read it in a post previously if I remember it correctly but cannot find it now.  I will let you know if I find it later.

Comment: (1) For problems FFNs solve, are they able to solve them with 100% accuracy? (2) Do FFNs sometimes take an unbounded amount of time to solve a problem instance? (3) Do FNNs fail to halt for some problem instances? (4) Can a FFN take as input an encoding of an FFN, a problem instance and a (partial) representation of an FFN's computation history, and determine whether the computation history is consistent with the input FFN's processing of the input problem instance? If any of the above can be answered definitively in the negative, FNNs cannot be Turing-equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are making an incorrect assumption here, hence apparent paradox. ***Universal approximation theorem*** states that a feed-forward network with a single hidden layer containing a finite number of neurons  can approximate **continuous functions** on **compact subsets** ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem)). Turing machine theorem encompasses wider range of functions, including **discrete** functions.

To my knowledge there is no proof that FFN are or are not Turing-complete (happy to be corrected here). There exists though a [proof](http://binds.cs.umass.edu/papers/1992_Siegelmann_COLT.pdf) that RNN are Turing-complete (as you said).

Comment: Thanks!  I am a little bit confused about whether "state" is required to be Turing-complete since in lambda calculus there seems to be no "states".

Comment: If we assume a mathematical model (not FFN) can approximate any function given enough parameters (not limited to continuous functions), can we construct such a model equivalent to Universal Turing machine?

Comment: Yes, that's close to the definition of a Turing machine AFAIK.